# Getting "[Errno 28] No space left on device" on AWS SageMaker with plenty of storage left

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a notebook instance on Amazon Sagemaker and my understanding is that notebooks by default have 5GB of storage.  I am running into `[Errno 28] No space left on device` on a notebook that worked just fine the last time I tried it.  I checked and I'm using approximately 1.5GB out of 5GB. I'm trying to download a bunch of files from my S3 bucket but I get the error even before one file is downloaded.  Additionally, the notebook no longer autosaves.

Has anyone run into this and figured out a way to fix it? I've already tried clearing all outputs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the persistent storage of your notebook up to 16Tb in the editing the notebook details on AWS console. This volume however is mounted under `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker`. Download your files under this folder and you'll see all the storage you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run `df -kh` to tell which FS is running out of disk space.
There's a root filesystem which is 100GB, and there's a user filesystem which size you can customize (default 5GB) ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-setup-working-env.html)).
Guess: I saw that, especially when using Docker, the root FS can run out of space.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to try to restart or kill the kernel. Sometimes some cells are left running and you may be trying to execute another operation. Sometimes logfiles also if you have any kill the space so try to remove all tertiary files that you are not using.

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own

Answer (score 0):

Often this is seen in cases when there are certain unused resources running.
The default FS size is 100GB.

If you are using SageMaker Studio, you can use [this][1] JupyterLab extension to automatically shuts down Kernels, Terminals and Apps in Sagemaker Studio when they are idle for a stipulated period of time. You will be able to configure an idle time limit using the user interface this extension provides.
[1]: https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-auto-shutdown-extension